# Valid Warehousing Strategy? Type6?

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, etl, data-warehouse

As a database user, I'm having problems interpreting the data in one of our tables at work. When I questioned the data team, the solution architects told me it was done this way on purpose because it is a "Type 6" table.

From my limited googling, I think a Type 6 should look like this:

```
+--------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| Customer_Key | Customer_Attrib1 | Customer_Attrib2 | Start_Date | End_Date   | Record Updated Date |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| 123          | 1                | A                | 1/1/2001   | 6/8/2004   | 6/9/2004            |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| 123          | 1                | A                | 6/9/2004   | 4/11/2016  | 4/12/2016           |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| 123          | 1                | A                | 4/12/2016  | 4/3/2017   | 4/4/2017            |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| 123          | 2                | B                | 4/4/2017   | 5/18/2017  | 5/19/2017           |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| 123          | 2                | B                | 5/19/2017  | 12/31/9999 | 5/19/2017           |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
```

The activity in question is the Customer_Attrib1, how it changed from 1 to 2 on 5/18/2017.

I like this style because *I can figure out what customer_attrib1 is at any point of time* by using the start and end dates:

```
select customer_attrib1 
from table 
where customer_key=123 
and '2017-03-01' between start_date and end_date;
```

However...

The table itself actually gets updated in arrears, to look like this:

```
+--------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| Customer_Key | Customer_Attrib1 | Customer_Attrib2 | Start_Date | End_Date   | Record Updated Date |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| 123          | 2                | A                | 1/1/2001   | 6/8/2004   | 5/19/2017           |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| 123          | 2                | A                | 6/9/2004   | 4/11/2016  | 5/19/2017           |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| 123          | 2                | A                | 4/12/2016  | 4/3/2017   | 5/19/2017           |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| 123          | 2                | B                | 4/4/2017   | 5/18/2017  | 5/19/2017           |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| 123          | 2                | B                | 5/19/2017  | 12/31/9999 | 5/19/2017           |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
```

Can you see how much trouble I have, if I want to go find what the customer_attrib1 was during March of 2016?

NOTE: There *is* a previous_customer_attrib1 column, but it also gets mass updated to the value of 1. I wanted to keep the table small enough to get the point across, which is why I didn't add it above.

**The big question**:  Is this a valid warehousing strategy? Is this really what Type 6 is? Or is my solution architect wrong.

**Follow up question**: Would the answer be different if customer_attrib1 was a foreign key to another table?

Comment: When you say "what the customer_attrib1 was during March of 2016", according to what state/date of the database? How is that different from using the second table? As of each Record Updated Date there is a version of things. You don't explain what "like this" means, but Record Updated Date is whatever it is, if an update or correction has been made, and no, you can't "figure out what customer_attrib1 is at any point of time by using the start and end dates" without it. PS How is either Type 6?

Comment: Some fields in a type-6 table always show the current value (these are type-1 fields - which are overwritten with changes).  Example: a data warehouse only contains current contact phones numbers - to prevent calls to old/incorrect numbers.  Would recommend you check with your data team why they do not retain old values in `Customer_Attrib1`.  They may be trying to prevent certain behaviours/outcomes.

Comment: I agree with @Rich.  Once you get past type-5 the names are not used consistently across the industry.  Your data team should be able to supply a definition for type-6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example looks like a plain ol Type 2 SCD. The second example looks like it is Type 1 (overwrite) on attribute 1 and Type 2 SCD on attribute 2.

Neither are a Type 6 as presented, which would be where you have a way to see both the history of the changes (in a Type 2 way, as per your first example) but also the current values, typically by holding a separate set of columns for the current values, or by linking to the current record. You mention the previous attrib 1 column, which is crucial to it being a Type 6. However you would not expect that to also be bulk updated, as otherwise you just get the one previous value, and you don't get to see any changes prior to that.

Different people refer to a Type 6 meaning different things. What you need in a type 6 is simply the value itself (which applies to the row at the time) and the current value (which is bulk updated when there is a change), along with (of course) the type 2 approach of creating new rows for each change.

To answer your question, yes, I can see how much trouble you have with the design that's been given to you. Its a valid strategy if and only if it meets the business requirements. These techniques are only there to help meet business needs.

If the attribute is a foreign key then it becomes a bit more tricky, and we'd need more info about how that foreign keyed table was tracking history to be able to answer whether that changes anything.